# pandas groupby two simmilar columns and two different

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this:

```
    ID | Name | Thing | belongs | match
    ---+------+-------+---------+-----
     1   John     10     1,2,3     9
     2   John     10      2,4      8
```

output should be:

```
John 10 1,2,3,2,4 9,9,9,8,8
```

How can i group them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def f(df):
    lol = df.belongs.str.split(',').tolist()
    lens = [len(lst) for lst in lol]
    belongs = ','.join(map(str, np.concatenate(lol)))
    match = ','.join(map(str, df.match.repeat(lens).tolist()))

    return pd.Series(dict(
            belongs=belongs,
            match=match
        ))

df.groupby(['Name', 'Thing']).apply(f).reset_index()

   Name  Thing    belongs      match
0  John     10  1,2,3,2,4  9,9,9,8,8
```

---

A slightly different approach.  Determining the differences is a task left for the reader.

```
def f(df):
    lens = df.belongs.str.count(',') + 1
    belongs = df.belongs.str.cat(sep=',')
    match = df.match.repeat(lens).map(str).str.cat(sep=',')

    return pd.Series(dict(
            belongs=belongs,
            match=match
        ))

print(df.groupby(['Name', 'Thing']).apply(f).reset_index())

   Name  Thing    belongs      match
0  John     10  1,2,3,2,4  9,9,9,8,8
```

Comment: i'm getting error on 'match' string - Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe') Can it be somehow resolved ?